# Storing / Modify / Using app settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I just require some advice / best practice / links.

Regular Web Application
C# and ASP.NET 4.0
MSSQL 2012
VSTUDIO 2013

I have built a web application + web admin console and would like to know the best way to use 
all the league settings/configurations that are stored in the database. I have built a hockey league management system + stats web site. Those settings/configuration can be modify. Each league can change there settings/configurations.

Some examples : Many league are using my system. When visiting the stats web site, league admin can choose to show or not show some column in the standings. They also would like to customized the order by column for grid that I have. When filling a form on the web site, the email to send the form to is unique for each league. I have about 20 settings like that and it can change quickly (more settings). Every settings and config are just boolean, integer or string values.

It is best to load all settings in session and play with it ?
Should I create a generic Class/DLL that handles all my possible settings ?
Other advice ... ?

Thanks everyone

Rick

P.S. Sorry for the bad english, not my first language !

Comment: Are all of the settings defined?  I other words, do you know all of the settings or are you planning to add more settings as you get new ideas/requests?

Comment: Hi, I will add more settings since clients are asking for more and more improvements/customization. ;-). They can change over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track and already answered most of your question.  For a web app, it is a fairly standard practice to load a user's settings into a session var upon login (unless you have multiple servers set up as a web farm).

Setting up a class, to wrap your settings, is good design too, because you can use strong types and add mechanisms for storing settings to your session & db.  If you ever change that approach, having it wrapped in a class will make it easier to refactor/re-engineer your approach.

Some people would say: store user settings as columns in one table.  Some would say you should normalize it so it acts more like a hash table.  Certainly, storing it as XML would be the simplest and most flexible, plus you can use XML serialization to get the settings in/out of a settings wrapper class.  Based on the (limited) description of your project, I think XML would be a little more work, but totally worth it.  That is what I would do.

Comment: Hi tgolisch, do you have any good trusted links for the XML part ? I'll try on my side to find info about it. Thanks !

Comment: S/O seems to frown-upon posting links to other web sites.  If I posted some code for XML serialization here it would be 2-4 files, 100-200 lines of code.  I find a lot of good (free) code from codeproject.com.  Do a search for ".net xml serialization" and you will get several hundred examples, with code.